# Define a Spring RestController via Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it possible to Define a Spring RestController (`@RestController` annotated class) *solely* in the Java Configuration (the class with `@Configuration` annotated in the method marked with `@Bean`)?

I have an application managed by spring boot (the version doesn't matter for the sake of the question, even the last one available). This application exposes some endpoints with REST, so there are several rest controllers, which in turn call the services (as usual).

Now depending on configuration (property in `application.yml`) I would like to avoid starting some services and, say 2 classes annotated with `@RestController` annotation because they deal with the "feature X" that I want to exclude.

I would like to configure all my beans via *Java configuration*, and this is a requirement. So my initial approach was to define all the beans (controllers and services) in a separate configuration which is found by spring boot during the scanning) and put a `@ConditionalOnProperty` on the configuration so that it will appear in one place:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyAppGeneralConfiguration {
  // here I define all the beans that are not relevant for "feature X"
  @Bean
  public ServiceA serviceA() {}
  ...
}

@Configuration 
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.featureX.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MyAppFeatureXConfiguration {
   // here I will define all the beans relevant for feature X:

  @Bean
  public ServiceForFeatureX1 serviceForFeatureX1() {}   

  @Bean
  public ServiceForFeatureX2 serviceForFeatureX2() {}   
}
```

With this approach My services do not have any spring annotations at all and I don't use `@Autowired` annotation as everything is injected via the constructors in `@Configuration` class:

```
// no @Service / @Component annotation
public class ServiceForFeatureX1 {}
```

Now my question is about the classes annotated with `@RestContoller` annotation. Say I have 2 Controllers like this:

```
@RestController
public class FeatureXRestController1 {
  ...
}

@RestController
public class FeatureXRestController2 {
 ...
}
```

Ideally I would like to define them in the Java Configuration as well, so that these two controllers won't even load when I disable the feature:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.featureX.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing=true)
public class MyAppFeatureXConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @RestController // this doesn't work because the @RestController has target Type and can't be applied 
                    // to methods
    public FeatureXRestController1 featureXRestController1() {
    }
```

So the question is basically is it possible to do that?

RestController is a Controller which is in turn a component hence its subject to component scanning. Hence if the feature X is disabled the rest controllers for feature X will still start loading  and fail 
because there won't be no "services" - beans excluded in the configuration, so spring boot won't be able to inject.

One way I thought about is to define a special annotation like `@FeatureXRestController` and make it `@RestController` and put `@ConditionalOnProperty` there but its still two places and its the best solution I could come up with:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.featureX.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing=true)
public @interface FeatureXRestController {
}

...
@FeatureXRestController
public class FeatureXRestController1 {...}

@FeatureXRestController
public class FeatureXRestController2 {...}
```

Comment: So you just want to start parts of your Application? Did you read about @Profile? This way you can differ which parts of your app run by a property which you can set as env var

Comment: Yes, exactly - so that the part will include rest controllers as well as other beans

Comment: With @Profile you can also create Application.properties per configuration if you Name it application-yourProfile.yml

Comment: As you're using Spring boot you can use conditional bean property as well https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html .

Comment: Well, i use conditional which is a generalization of profile (since spring 4 @profile is implemented as a conditional) so the solution I've offered in the end of the question indeed uses this technique. I'm asking whether there is  a better solution that I could come up with.

Comment: Meta annotation is the way to go in your case. It will be DRY and you should be using @Profile /@ConditionalOn/ect spring annotation to enable /disable desired features

Comment: @Alexander.Furer Yeah, I believe you mean the solution I’ve described at the end of the question with `@FeatureXRestController`... The best solution I could come up with :) Thanks for your opinion.  Probably if `@RestController` wasn’t defined as  a `@Component` in spring it was better in this case...

Comment: You can also import configuration dynamically. See @Import /selector annotation /  other methods to dynamically registered beans, just make sure they are not picked up by default beans scanner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've Found a relatively elegant workaround that might be helpful for the community: 
I don't use a specialized meta annotation like I suggested in the question and annotate the controller of Feature X with the regular `@RestController` annotation:

```
@RestController
public class FeatureXController {
  ...
}
```

The Spring boot application class can be "instructed" to not load RestControllers during the component scanning exclusion filter. For the sake of example in the answer I'll use the built-in annotation filter, but in general custom filters can be created for more sophisticated (real) cases:

```
// Note the annotation - component scanning process won't recognize classes annotated with RestController, so from now on all the rest controllers in the application must be defined in `@Configuration` classes.
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(RestController.class))
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now, since I want the rest controller to be loaded only if Feature X is enabled, I create the corresponding method in the FeatureXConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "mayapp.featureX.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class FeatureXConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FeatureXService featureXService () {
        return new FeatureXService();
    }

    @Bean
    public FeatureXRestController featureXRestController () {
        return new FeatureXRestController(featureXService());
    }
}
```

Although component scanning process doesn't load the rest controllers, the explicit bean definition "overrides" this behavior and the rest controller's bean definition is created during the startup. Then Spring MVC engine analyzes it and due to the presence of the `@RestController` annotation it exposes the corresponding end-point as it usually does.

Comment: I'll accept my own answer (yeah, it sounds weird, I know :) ) in 23 hours if no-one posts better solution

Comment: have a look at this on the extreme bottom of page https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/deprecated-list.html ie ``@bean`` annotation is going to be deprecated, So this solution will fail

Comment: @TanmayNaik Just the field `autowire` within the `@Bean` annotation is deprecated not the entire annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use local classes in the java config. E.e.

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppFeatureXConfiguration  {

  @Bean
  public FeatureXRestController1 featureXRestController1(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {

     @RestController
     class FeatureXRestController1Bean extends FeatureRestController1 {
     }

     FeatureXRestController1Bean featureBean = new FeatureXRestController1Bean();

     // You don't need this line if you use constructor injection
     autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(featureBean);
  
     return featureBean;
  } 
}
```

Then you can omit the `@RestController` annotation on the "real" implementation, but use the other annotations like `@RequestMapping` as usual.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public class FeatureXRestController1 {

    @RequestMapping(value="/somePath/{someId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findSomething(@PathVariable String someId) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Sine the `FeatureXRestController1` doesn't have a `@RestController` annotation, it is not a `@Component` anymore and thus will not be picked up through component scan.

The `MyAppFeatureXConfiguration` returns a bean that is a `@RestController`. This `FeatureXRestController1Bean` extends the `FeatureXRestController1` and thus has all the methods and request mappings of the superclass.

Since the `FeatureXRestController1Bean` is a local class it is not included in a component scan. This does the trick for me ;)

**EDIT**

> I have used this solution and worked fine. Unfortunately it stopped working since SpringBoot 3.2.1

I tested it with SpringBoot 3.2.3 and it worked.

Steps to reproduce

1. Create a simple Spring Web project using [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web)
2. Add a simple controller as a pojo

   ```
    public class MyController {
        public String sayHello(String who) {
            return "Hello " + who;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Create an ApplicationConfig

   ```
    @Bean
    public MyController myRestController(){

        @RestController
        class SpringRestController extends MyController {

            @GetMapping(path = "sayHello")
            @Override
            public String sayHello(@RequestParam(name="who") String who) {
                return super.sayHello(who);
            }
        }

        return new SpringRestController();
    }
   ```
4. Build and Run the app

   ```
    ./mvnw spring-boot:run
   ```

   or if you created a gradle project

   ```
    ./gradlew bootRun
   ```
5. Access the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/sayHello?who=Ren%C3%A9`

PS: I even tried the autowiring I in my original answer. It worked too.

Comment: I have used this solution and worked fine. Unfortunately it stopped working since SpringBoot 3.2.1, the bean is in the context, it has the @RestController annotation but I think somehow it ignores the rest annotations and does not expose any paths anymore. I opened an issue regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I like both the solutions presented above. However, I came up with another one which worked for me and is pretty clean.

So, I decided to create my beans only using @Configuration classes, and I gave up the @RestController annotations entirely. I put the @Configuration class for web controllers in a separate package, so that I can pass the class descriptor to the @ComponentScan or @ContextConfiguration annotations whenever I want to enable the creation of controller beans. The most important part is to add the @ResponseBody annotation to all controller classes, above the class name, to preserve the REST controller properties. Very clean.

The drawback is that the controller classes are not recognized by the @WebMvcTest annotation, and I need to create the beans for all my controllers every time I do a MockMvc test for one controller. As I have just four controllers though, I can live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a better idea to use the basePackages property of @ComponentScan to restrict what classes SB will scan? e.g. :-

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.myapp.config")
```

so all your configuration classes are in the `org.myapp.config` package.

Seems pretty neat to me?